# Use join to connect strings by periods

Tags: c#, .net

Trying to get a string
Trying to do something like this

```
string product;
foreach (Cart item in items)
{
    // join item.text by periods and assign it to product variable  
}
```

Should be simple I think, but I just don't use join enough and I'm having problems.

items should be "product1", "product2"

and turn into "product1.product2"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The loop is not nessesary you just can use `Select` and `string.Join` from LINQ

```
string.Join(".", items.Select(c => c.Text))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can use LINQ you can do a simple `Select` to map items into just strings and join them.

```
String.Join(".", items.Select(i => i.text))
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have List of strings and want to join by some separator use String.Join

```
String.Join(separator,Collection)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to concatenate all the products with a period

Not sure if that is what you want to do but this works

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

class MainClass {
  public static void Main (string[] args) {
    var items = new List<CartItem>();
    items.Add(new CartItem("product1"));
    items.Add(new CartItem("product2"));
    items.Add(new CartItem("product3"));

    var product = items.Select(_ => _.Text).Aggregate((p1, p2) => p1+"."+p2);

    Console.WriteLine(product);
  }
}

class CartItem {
  internal CartItem(string text) {
    Text = text;
  }
  public string Text {get;}
}
```

Edit: note this is not as efficient as String.Join but an alternative syntax that produces the same output